# Will Google Music sync my iTunes playlists?

Tags: google-play-music, itunes

I have been invited to the Google Music Beta, and in setting up the service, I chose to upload music from "My Music" folder rather than the "iTunes" option, simply because my music files are in the root folder of "My Music" and not in the "iTunes" folder "My Music." I was unsure of whether the "iTunes" option in Google Music only takes the music from the iTunes folder. However, in choosing "My Music" as my upload source, will it lack my iTunes playlists when I play from my Android Device?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Originally synced it with "My Music" folder option and no playlists showed up. Restarted with option of "iTunes" and in a few minutes my playlists showed up without having to resync all the music.